# Ubuntu 23.04 new installer crashing

Tags: system-installation, 23.04

This is more of a bug report than a question; I am now without access to Ubuntu web.

The new installer fails to load, most of the time. When it loads, it contains graphical artifacts, and crashes later on.

I have tried to run it from a console and got these errors:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-desktop-installer
flutter: INFO ubuntu_desktop_installer: Logging to /var/log/installer/ubuntu_desktop_installer.log
flutter: INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds

(ubuntu_desktop_installer:5851): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 00:41:49.042: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2613: signal 'require-surrounding-text' is invalid for instance '0x7f2060006ea0' of type 'IBusInputContext'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-desktop-installer
flutter: INFO ubuntu_desktop_installer: Logging to /var/log/installer/ubuntu_desktop_installer.log
flutter: INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds

(ubuntu_desktop_installer:5959): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 00:42:29.885: ../../../gobject/gsignal.ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-desktop-installer
flutter: INFO ubuntu_desktop_installer: Logging to /var/log/installer/ubuntu_desktop_installer.log
flutter: INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds

(ubuntu_desktop_installer:5851): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 00:41:49.042: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2613: signal 'require-surrounding-text' is invalid for instance '0x7f2060006ea0' of type 'IBusInputContext'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-desktop-installer
flutter: INFO ubuntu_desktop_installer: Logging to /var/log/installer/ubuntu_desktop_installer.log
flutter: INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds

(ubuntu_desktop_installer:5959): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 00:42:29.885: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2613: signal 'require-surrounding-text' is invalid for instance '0x7f345c006c60' of type 'IBusInputContext'
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 2 relocs 0
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000 0x7f3461021000 0x15000 0x80000
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000001 00000006 00000004 00000000 00000004 0x7f34714bc000 0x215000 0x1000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-desktop-installer
flutter: INFO ubuntu_desktop_installer: Logging to /var/log/installer/ubuntu_desktop_installer.log
flutter: INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds

(ubuntu_desktop_installer:6064): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 00:42:45.461: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2613: signal 'require-surrounding-text' is invalid for instance '0x7f8f88006f60' of type 'IBusInputContext'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-desktop-installer
flutter: INFO ubuntu_desktop_installer: Logging to /var/log/installer/ubuntu_desktop_installer.log
flutter: INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds

(ubuntu_desktop_installer:6170): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 00:42:56.209: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2613: signal 'require-surrounding-text' is invalid for instance '0x7f1234006e90' of type 'IBusInputContext'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
c:2613: signal 'require-surrounding-text' is invalid for instance '0x7f345c006c60' of type 'IBusInputContext'
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch5: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 2 relocs 0
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000000 00000002 00000004 00000004 00000000 0x7f3461021000 0x15000 0x80000
nouveau: ch5: buf 00000001 00000006 00000004 00000000 00000004 0x7f34714bc000 0x215000 0x1000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-desktop-installer
flutter: INFO ubuntu_desktop_installer: Logging to /var/log/installer/ubuntu_desktop_installer.log
flutter: INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds

(ubuntu_desktop_installer:6064): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 00:42:45.461: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2613: signal 'require-surrounding-text' is invalid for instance '0x7f8f88006f60' of type 'IBusInputContext'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ubuntu-desktop-installer
flutter: INFO ubuntu_desktop_installer: Logging to /var/log/installer/ubuntu_desktop_installer.log
flutter: INFO subiquity_server: Waiting server up to 90 seconds

(ubuntu_desktop_installer:6170): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 00:42:56.209: ../../../gobject/gsignal.c:2613: signal 'require-surrounding-text' is invalid for instance '0x7f1234006e90' of type 'IBusInputContext'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
...
nouveau:    0x00000000
ubuntu_desktop_installer: ../nouveau/pushbuf.c:730: nouveau_pushbuf_data: Assertion `kref' failed.
```

Seems like the old driver for nVidia graphics card is the cause?
Can I overcome this somehow? E.g. use some safe-mode installation?

Thanks

Comment: Have you explored the system logs for clues?  Did media verification complete successfully?  Were any other issues visible that can give details etc..  either way this isn't the place for bug reports (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) and Ubuntu 23.04 has two installers available for use; so why not use `ubiquity` if you can't find the issue with the default installer/ISO.

Comment: I'm having this issue too. I tried running the program `ubuntu-desktop-installer` because that's the program the icon on the desktop links to. I'd like to try this alternative installer though. When I type `ubiquity` into a terminal, I get `command 'ubiquity' not found`. Is this a program that is supposed to be already present when one boots up Ubuntu to begin installing it?

Comment: I tried installing it with `sudo apt install ubiquity` and I got error output that included a Python traceback that included `AttributeError: No frontend available; tried gtk_ui, kde_ui`.

Comment: @MattWelke the `ubiquity` installer is pre-setup on the *alternate* or *legacy* ISO.  Download the *legacy* ISO and use it normally; it'll run the pre-configured `ubiquity` installer.  You select which installer you'll use at download time (*when selecting the ISO*)

Comment: The media verification was ok. The logs do not contain anything supsicious.